# List all context keys in a velocity template

Tags: velocity

Is there a way to list all keys in a velocity context from the template that is currently being expanded? I've done this in the past by including a reference to the context in the context. I guess this method is okay, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the traditional way, and there is nothing wrong with it.  If you are using VelocityTools, you can use the ContextTool to accomplish that and a bit more.